# How to convert Gradle testImplementation testFixtures('com.bla:bla-bla:master_d171111') to Kotlin Gradle?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am having a problem resolving class inside Kotlin test, there are similar Java projects which are using:

```
testImplementation testFixtures('com.bla:bla-bla:master_d171111')
```

And class from there only resolves when both `testImplementation` and `testFixtures` are declared.

Kotlin gradle behaves weird, first of all, I can only declare single:

```
testFixtures("com.bla:bla-bla:master_d171111")
```

(which on the side note doesn't break gradle import if I put rubbish between brackets, so does it even work?)

On top of that IntelliJ diligently highlights all syntax for dependencies in yellow, but not for `testFixtures` which is white for some reason.

Could anyone please suggest equivalent for:

```
testImplementation testFixtures('com.bla:bla-bla:master_d171111')
```

Individually declaring doesn't help either class is not resolved, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

```
testImplementation(testFixtures("com.bla:bla-bla:master_d171111"))
```

No worries, found myself eventually.